# Why is e seen in seen in gravity? (catenary curves)

Tags: calculus-of-variations, hyperbolic-functions, eulers-number-e

I have been learning about how catenary curves, described as a rope suspended between two poles supported by only its own weight can be represented as some transformation of the curve cosh(x). This function is derived from the number e, and I am wondering why exactly e is present here in this phenomenon?

Comment: looks like you need to do write a bit more on what you are talking about. but also since you mentioned hyperbolic functions in your tag then it is no surprise about e, that should actually make it obvious.

Comment: It follows from the differential equation it should satisfy.

Comment: $\cosh(x\ln2)$ involves powers of $2$ so you can think of it as powers, rather than powers of $e$.

Answer (score 3):

The equation for a catenary is $y=\frac a2\left(e^{\frac xa}+e^{-\frac xa}\right)$.  If you want to use some other base for the exponentials, that just changes the value of $a$.  For example, if you want to use $5$, note that $e^{\frac xa}=\left(e^{\log 5}\right)^\frac x{a \log 5}=5^\frac x{a \log 5}$ and you can absorb it into the value of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special with that, when we write down the [governing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Derivation_of_equations_for_the_curve) for equilibrium, under the load due to the self weight of the rope, we obtain a differential equation which has that shape as a solution.

Note that when the rope is not much sloped then the shape is very similar to a parabolic arch, which indeed if the shape of equilibrium for an uniform load (i.e. as for the cables of [suspension bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Suspension_bridge_curve)).